# Object Released too soon with iOS 5 ARC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

I'm a newbie on objective-c programming language and I've noticed a strange behavior in memory management.
With iOS 5 ARC is enabled by default but an object is released too soon, maybe someone can give me some advice.

This is the case:

I've a Dao object which retrieve data from a SQLite database using Core Data PersistenceStore.
This Dao implements a method "getAllAuthors"

In my viewController in viewWillAppear method I load this data and data are loaded but when I populate a tableView the objects are (null).

I post some code:

```
@synthesize authors;
@synthesize authorsTable;
@synthesize dao;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"author in viewDidLoad: %@", [[authors objectAtIndex:0] name]);
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    dao = [[CrossoverDao alloc] init];
    authors = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[dao getAllAuthors]];
    [authorsTable reloadData];
    NSLog(@"author in viewWillAppear: %@", [[authors objectAtIndex:0] name]);
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [authorsTable reloadData];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    NSLog(@"author in viewWillDisappear: %@", [[authors objectAtIndex:0] name]);
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    NSLog(@"author in viewDidDisappear: %@", [[authors objectAtIndex:0] name]);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource datasource

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"[AuthorsViewController::cellForRowAtIndexPath] Constructing row at indexPath: %d",     indexPath.row);
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
                             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        if(indexPath.section == 0)
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]     initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        else
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]     initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [[authors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[authors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] bio];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tv numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"author in numberOfRowsInSection: %@", [[authors objectAtIndex:0] name]);
    return [authors count];
}
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath the author is null. Any clue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the header file, it may be that you have weak references set for dao and authors instead of strong.

Comment: have you tried `[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ensure that you set your properties using the synthesized accessors so that ARC knows that you want to keep them if they are strong (here it just inserted releases at the end of your `viewWillAppear` method). Change

```
dao = [[CrossoverDao alloc] init];
authors = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[dao getAllAuthors]];
```

to

```
self.dao = [[CrossoverDao alloc] init];
self.authors = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[dao getAllAuthors]];
```

Comment: They NSManaged objects so properties are @dynamic, can I change them to synthesize?

Comment: At the top of you code you have synthesize authors;
synthesize authorsTable; synthesize dao;

Comment: I Understood, so I need to refer object with self, sorry but I'm a newbie and I still have to understand all of these. I changed the code like you said but tableview still doesn't populate because the author is null

Comment: What does NSLog(@"author in viewWillAppear: %@", [[authors objectAtIndex:0] name]); print out?

Comment: First time view is loaded it prints the correct name, then always (null)

Comment: And this also happens with the accessors (self.)?

Comment: "First time view is loaded it prints the correct name" - at what point does the array get nulled? does the tableview get filled with data first time and then crash when you scroll? can you post your header file?

Answer (score 1):

```
dao = [[CrossoverDao alloc] init];
authors = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[dao getAllAuthors]];
[authorsTable reloadData];
NSLog(@"author in viewWillAppear: %@", [[authors objectAtIndex:0] name]);
```

This should be done in viewDidLoad or loadView method of your controller.
In viewWillAppear you generally just request a UI update.

Comment: Even modifying and loading data in viewDidLoad in the table population methods objects are null

Answer (score -3):

I've not used ios5 ARC, but maybe you could you try retaining in viewWillAppear and releasing in viewWillDisappear?

```
[authors retain];
```

Comment: You will get build error if you try to use any [memory management methods](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#misc.special_methods.retain) when compiling with ARC